# How can I get the entry of some commands in .bash_history through a script in centos?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, centos-6

writing a python script to generate commands is working and the commands are getting executed in bash, but they are not getting entered in .bash_history.What should I do so that those commands are shown in .bash_history ?
my py file is as follows:-

```
import os
import sh

def main():
    bashcommand = "top"
    bashcommand1 = "ls"
    bashcommand2 = "vi exp1.txt"
    os.system(bashcommand)
    os.system(bashcommand1)
    os.system(bashcommand2)
main()

sh.cd('/root')
print(sh.pwd())
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: `os.system` executes commands using `/bin/sh`. When Bourne Again Shell is called as `/bin/sh`, it does not write anything to history. See [os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) and [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

As Sami Laine commented, os.system uses a shell that is often not bash. on top of this, `bash -c 'command'` does not write to .bash_history. You could, of course, just make something like this:

```
import os
def runcommand(command):
    with open(os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_history'), 'a') as f:
        f.writelines([command])
    os.system(command)
```